# PHP&NetBeans: предупреждения о переопределении переменных

Tags: php, netbeans

При переопределении заданной ранее в PHP переменной NetBeans даёт рекомендацию в виде предупреждения о том, что переменную следует определять только один раз. Есть какая-либо ещё причина следовать этой рекомендации, кроме указанного "повышения читабельности"?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вообще не рекомендовал переопределять переменную, а использовать ее только для того, для чего она была создана. Представьте себе, вы определили некоторую переменную `$users` в которой записана коллекция пользователей, зарегистрированных в системе, а потом решили ее переопределить, записав в нее массив `id` пользователей, которых нужно удалить. В итоге возникает путаница при чтении вашего кода. Я думаю не составит большого труда создать еще одну переменную.

P.S. Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос

Comment: Всё правильно Вы поняли. Если рассматривать тот случай, что Вы привели в пример, то я с Вами согласен, но бывает, что мы совершаем цепочку преобразований над перемененной. Например, мы принимаем значение номера телефона из поля ввода, затем удаляем лишние пробелы, затем ещё что-то с ним делаем. В данном случае если на каждом этапе определять новую переменную, этих самых переменный станет очень много.

Comment: Да, пользуйтесь областью видимости переменной, создавайте отдельные методы, в которых определяйте ваши новые переменные, тогда за границами этого метода не будет путанницы. Например `$phone = $this->cleanPhone();` `function cleanPhone() {$phone = $this->getPhone(); return $this->clean($phone);}`

Comment: И я рекомендую почитать книгу Роберта Мартина "Чистый код". Достаточно простая и очень информативная книга

Comment: Хорошо, почитаю, я стремлюсь к чистоте кода.